# Optimizing jQuery dynamic adding of inset border effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, random, jquery-effects

I'm not that experienced with jquery and javascript but I managed to get this code working for my Drupal website (I've included the beginning and end of the required Drupal jQuery calling code for reference, as the 'context' part makes it work with Ajax refreshing there so as a reference of sorts, feel free to ignore)

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.borderfarba = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        var nmbr = 1; /// this will be a counter
        var backcolor; /// here I store the generated random color
        $(".movierow", context).each(function () {

            /// I declare a class + a number from the counter
            var clrclass = "clr" + nmbr;

            /// I add this class to each .movierow class 
            /// which is inside a div containing divs with the other classes
            $(this).addClass(clrclass);

            /// storing the random color
            backcolor = get_random_color();

            /// pass the  class and color value to function
            addborder(clrclass, backcolor);

            /// up the counter
            nmbr++;
        });


        function addborder(clrclass, backcolor) {
            /// before the inset border effect I also
            /// apply the backcolor to a title and rating field
            /// that appear over the image

            $("." + clrclass + " .views-field-field-screenrate").css("background", backcolor);
            $("." + clrclass + " .screentitle").css("background", backcolor);

            /// apply the inset border effect
            $("." + clrclass + " img").insetBorder({
                borderColor: backcolor,
                inset: 5
            });
        }

        /// randomization functions
        function rand(min, max) {
            return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1), 10) + min;
        }

        function get_random_color() {
            var h = rand(40, 130);
            var s = rand(30, 75);
            var l = rand(40, 60);
            return 'hsl(' + h + ',' + s + '%,' + l + '%)';
        }

        /// add a nice slide down/up effect
        /// on mouse in/out for the title
        $(".movierow").hover(
        function () { $(this).children(".screentitle").slideDown(); },
        function () { $(this).children(".screentitle").slideUp(); }
        );

    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

The point is I want a  new random color within a specified range (like in my case from reddish hues to green) applied to the jQuery inset border effect found [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/InsetBorderEffect/) which is then applied to each image on my page (which are generated dynamically). PS. I think I found the random color generation code snippet somewhere around here, so thanks to that one person, don't want credit where it's not due.

Thus I used a loop which adds a new class to each image and then applies the inset border function to each class.

I'm wondering if there's any way of optimizing this code to be more efficient, as this is the only way I figured how to do it.

Cheers and thanks for any advice, hoping to improve my under par programming skills

UPDATE I have modified the code a bit (and added comments), as I needed the same random background color for 2 additional fields that appear over the image (title, rating)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a question...

Why do you convert 'nmbr' to a string?

```
  /// I declare a class + a number from the counter
  var clrclass = "clr" + nmbr.toString();
  /// I add this class to each .movierow class 
  /// which is inside a div containing divs with the other classes
  $(this).addClass(clrclass);
```

Wouldn't this be simpler?...

```
   $(this).addClass('clr'+nmbr);
```

Otherwise, your code looks very performant to me, but I'm far from an expert.

Comment: Indeed you're right, I don't need to convert, thanks. Added that automatically, bad habit from switching between languages.                   But I think I still need to keep it in the variable, as I'm passing it around other functions.